# Manually adding a vectored exception handler

Tags: c++, c, winapi, assembly

I'm working on a way to add/remove/insert vectored exception handlers on Windows. So far I reversed AddVectoredExceptionHandler and found the structure for a single node which looks like this:

```
typedef struct _VECTORED_HANDLER_NODE
{
    _VECTORED_HANDLER_NODE *PrevNode;
    _VECTORED_HANDLER_NODE *NextNode;
    BOOL IsNodeAllocated;
    PVOID EncodedHandler;
}VECTORED_HANDLER_NODE, *PVECTORED_HANDLER_NODE;
```

I'm using hardcoded addresses to find the start of the linked list (the head) which is at `ntdll!0x7DF74744`

At the moment I can insert into the linked list using this code:

```
void InsertHandler(PVECTORED_EXCEPTION_HANDLER cb, size_t pos)
{
    size_t counter = 1;
    veh_node *head = reinterpret_cast<veh_node*>(WINDOWS_7_VEH_HEAD),
             *first = head->NextNode,
             *end = head->NextNode;

    do
    {
        if(counter == pos)
        {
            break;
        }

        ++counter;
        first = first->NextNode;

    } while(first != end);

    // Copy the contents over
    veh_node *newNode = new veh_node();

    newNode->PrevNode = first->PrevNode;
    newNode->NextNode = first;
    newNode->EncodedHandler = EncodePointer(cb);
    newNode->IsNodeAllocated = TRUE;

    // Redirect the old pointers
    // to include the new node
    auto beforeNode = first->PrevNode;
    beforeNode->NextNode = newNode;

    first->PrevNode = newNode;
}
```

And the linked list looks like this:

[image: Linked list of handlers]

This is what the linked list looks like when using AddVectoredExceptionHandler:

[image: AddVectoredExceptionHandler linked list]

HEAD is the first data structure in the linked list while MEM(x) is the x'th data structure inside of the linked list. Cont denotes the decoded pointer which is the address of the callback function.

As you can see, other than the dynamic allocations causing different addresses, the output is the same. This means that I'm adding to the linked list correctly. The problem arises when I cause an exception since my handler is never called.
Instead the program just raises an exception and crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be your VECTORED_HANDLER_NODE is not correct and there are additional fields?

Comment: Is this C, C++, DontKnow or Dontcare?

Comment: What bothers me is that in those entries, the prev and next containing the same address. That often means that it's the only element in doubly linked list. As if they were not elements of a list, but heads of different lists.

Comment: I checked against the disassembly and it seems to be right. I won't say I'm 100% sure but I'm confident. Plus the output is the same as the one by Microsoft so it's probably correct.

@turboscrew The last node points back to the first one. I checked the nodes with 3 elements and my nodes are a replica of Microsoft's (I encode the handler too). I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: But if there is only one element, the last node == the first node. Then 'next' and 'prev' doesn't lead to anywhere else.

Comment: @turboscrew In my screenshots there are 2 nodes (MEM1 & MEM2) besides the head node. Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @user5505736: Oh yes, true. I should have read more carefully.

Comment: Maybe you just have to put a breakpoint and/or watchpoint there to see what happens. (I'm not sure if windbg supports watchpoints. It probably depends on the HW.)

Comment: How did you figured out the start of the linked list? Is there a fast way to get it?

Comment: @greenpiece The pointer to the start of the linked list is a global variable in ntdll.dll. You can either hardcode the address for your version of ntdll.dll or if you want a more portable approach just signature scan for the data. Read my updated answer to see an implementation I made for this.

Comment: This global variable is named `LdrpVectorHandlerList` (just for the sake of completeness). Its address may be watched in WinDbg, for example, with the following command: `x /0 ntdll!*HandlerList*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue a while back but only saw that this stood unanswered so I shall answer it now. The problem wasn't with the addresses or the data structures but with the fact that with every call to AddVectoredExceptionHandler Windows does a check to see if the chain of nodes contains only 1 node and if so does this:

```
   if ( (RTL_VEH_NODE *)FirstNodeInChain->NextNode == FirstNodeInChain )// Check if only 1 handler currently exists
      _interlockedbittestandset(
        (volatile signed __int32 *)(*(_QWORD *)(*MK_FP(__GS__, 48i64) + 96i64) + 80i64),
        arg31 + 2);
```

I also realized that all of this has already been reversed and a C version is located at:

https://git.reactos.org/?p=reactos.git;a=blob;f=reactos/lib/rtl/vectoreh.c

For more clarity, here's an implementation I made in C++ of an iterator that walks the vectored exception handler linked list:

https://github.com/Maktm/hadesmem/blob/master/include/memory/hadesmem/detail/vectored_handler_list.hpp
https://github.com/Maktm/hadesmem/blob/master/include/memory/hadesmem/detail/vectored_handler.hpp

Comment: Can you please explain what the reason is in more details?